# How to display an element for three seconds after all other elements have been loaded and displayed?

Tags: javascript, html

When loading an HTML page, what function in JavaScript do you use to make an element display three seconds after all other elements have been loaded and displayed?

Comment: `window.onload` + `setTimeout`.

Comment: Are you trying to make your element appear after everything else has loaded, or disappear after everything has loaded?  It's not clear from your wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout`.

### Make an element show up after 3 seconds

http://jsfiddle.net/1cv9xsn5/1/

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="threeSeconds" class="hidden">Won't show up for 3 seconds</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// attach to window.onload
setTimeout(function(){

    var modifiedClass = document.getElementById('threeSeconds').className.replace(/\bhidden\b/, '');
    document.getElementById('threeSeconds').className = modifiedClass;

}, 3000);
```

### Make an element disappear up after 3 seconds

http://jsfiddle.net/1cv9xsn5/

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="threeSeconds">Here I am, for three seconds</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// attach to window.onload
setTimeout(function(){

    document.getElementById('threeSeconds').className += ' hidden';

}, 3000);
```

You should attach the `setTimeout` to the `window.onload` event. If you attach to `document.onload` as suggested by davidkonrad, images and external content may not be loaded yet.