# How to remove element from dom after few seconds in ember

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I want to show this element only for 5 seconds and after that needs to remove from the dom.

```
{{#if canShow}}
  <div>
     This is block
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

Please help me to solve. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display an element for three seconds after all other elements have been loaded and displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803859/how-to-display-an-element-for-three-seconds-after-all-other-elements-have-been-l)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a modifier that, when added to an element, will remove the element from the DOM after a certain period of time.

First install `ember-modifier` (this is installed by default in new Ember projects): `ember install ember-modifier`

Then create a new modifier `ember g modifier remove-after`.

```js
// app/modifiers/remove-after.js

import { modifier } from 'ember-modifier';

export default modifier(function removeAfter(element, [delay]) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    element.remove();
  }, delay);
});
```

```
<div {{remove-after 3000}}>Will be removed after 3 seconds</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an Ember component you can use:

```js
init() {
  Ember.run.later(() => {
    this.set('canView', false) // Or you can toggleProperty here
  }, 5000);
}
```